# Expected values normal order statistics

Tags: expected-value, order-statistics

Given this equation pertaining to algorithm AS 177 ([from Royston, 1982](https://imaging.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/statswiki/FAQ/Corder?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=royston.pdf)):

> In a sample of size $n$ the expected value of the $r$th largest order statistic is given by
> $$E(r,\,n)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\{1-\Phi(x)\}^{r-1}\{\Phi(x)\}^{n-r}\phi(x)dx,$$
> where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\tfrac12x^2)$ and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^z\phi(z)dz$.

I have been trying to code this (really the expected normal order statistic of the Terry-Hoeffding Test) into Python with some difficulty.
I can code everything up to the integral and I can also get the CDF and PDF functions.
Where I am confused is the $x$ (the actual value?) before the curly brackets and the $dx$ that follows the PDF. 
Knowing little of mathematical notation, I am guessing I multiply the first fraction by $x$ times everything in the 2 sets of curly brackets and PDF but that doesn't seem correct. Also everything after "where" is Greek to me (literally and figuratively).

Any help in helping me understand this equation so that I can convert it to code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In light of @GNUSupporter8964民主女神 地下教會's comment, I've rewritten the excerpt.

Comment: Thanks, @J.G. for choosing to help instead of punish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, once you install `scipy`:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import binom
from scipy.stats import norm

inf, phi, Phi = float('inf'), norm.pdf, norm.cdf

def E(r, n):
    def f(x):   
        F = Phi(x)
        return x*(1-F)**(r-1)*F**(n-r)*phi(x)
    return r*binom(n, r)*quad(f, -inf, inf)[0]
```

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html) & [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

Comment: How does your answer clarify the notations $x$ and $dx$ that confuse OP?  Your answer doesn't contain "$dx$".

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神 地下教會 No, it wouldn't; `quad(f, a, b)[0]` means $\int_a^bf(x)dx$. But, as my penuiltimate line shows, the $x$ is just a factor in the integrand $f$ (`f`).

Comment: @J.G. Many thanks! Follow-up question posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960723/normal-order-statistic-for-terry-hoeffding-test

Comment: It is worth mentioning here that, for reasons I do not yet understand, using from statistics import NormalDist and NormalDist().pdf, NormalDist().cdf instead of norm.pdf, norm.cdf runs over 40 times faster.

Comment: @DanceParty On the other hand, the `scipy` option would be more efficient to generate a large number of samples, as long as you exploit `numpy` vectorization.