# Normal Order Statistic for Terry-Hoeffding Test

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

[Related to this question:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960622/expected-values-normal-order-statistics?noredirect=1#comment8168070_3960622)

I am trying to replicate the numbers found in the third column of the table on page 189 [from this article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIxSH6bCH1bJP0Ndg7TZVX3PoxkT4QlO/view?usp=sharing) (E(V^ri)) in Python by way of the Terry-Hoeffding Normal Scores test. Further explanation is provided on page 184. I am trying to locate Harter, 1961 to include it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps without realizing it, you've basically asked the same question twice. Eq. [1] in the paper is $E(V^k)=-E(V^{N+1-k})$. In Table 2 rank $1$ scores $-1$ times what rank $8$ scores, so $N=8$. The code I provided in your other question [finds $E(1,\,8)$ to be $1.4236$](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/DisastrousCarefulPrintablecharacter#main.py), the value given to rank $7$, or $-1$ times the value given to rank $1$. In other words, $V(r)=-E(r,\,N)$. (My linked code indents with two spaces at a time, instead of the four used in my other answer.)

Comment: Thanks again! I had an error in my code but now it works exactly as you described it. You just helped someone across the greatest obstacle in their dissertation. :)

Comment: @DanceParty Consider it a seasonal gift.