# Terry Hoeffding Normal Scores test (Further Explanation Requested)

Tags: order-statistics

I am working with a colleague trying to understand the Terry Hoeffding normal Scores test. We have gotten help in this post: [Normal Order Statistic for Terry-Hoeffding Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960723/normal-order-statistic-for-terry-hoeffding-test) to get to a certain point, but we are still missing a piece. We are trying to figure out how to calculate the Var(C), more specifically, how did was the 18.6633 calculated.

The article: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIxSH6bCH1bJP0Ndg7TZVX3PoxkT4QlO/view

Earlier post about it from my colleague: [Expected values normal order statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960622/expected-values-normal-order-statistics?noredirect=1#comment8168070_3960622)

[image]

Comment: I've replaced your link to an image with the image itself, but it's custom here to typeset mathematics in images when feasible. (Also, adding more of the relevant data would help people answer your question about where the particular figure $18.6\ldots$ comes from.)

Comment: Apologies, this has been solved!